# Plugin doesn't show up when running twistd

Tags: python, twisted, twistd

I created a test twistd plugin following the MyProject example here:

https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tap.html

but when I run `twistd --help` from the project root, the `myproject` program doesn't appear.

`twistd --version` returns

`twistd (the Twisted daemon) 21.7.0`

Does anyone have any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Is your refrigerator running? Sorry I mean is your project running?

Comment: There's nothing in `myproject` directory. I just created the example plugin with the directory structure as in the tutorial

Comment: And once you made it did you run it? "Now running twistd --help should print myproject in the list of available subcommands, followed by the description that we specified in the plugin. twistd -n myproject would, assuming we defined a MyFactory factory inside myproject , start a listening server on port 1235 with that factory."

Comment: Maybe I'm not sure what you mean by running the project. When I run `twistd -n myproject` I get `Unknown command: myproject`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think you have to take the sample script they provided and run it `python myproject.py` so that there is a service active on port 1235 which twistd will recognize.

Comment: @bitcoinvenv did you get solution around this